# Бонус за реферала после подписки, telebot

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot, telebot

Проверка не выполняется, ну тоесть баланс и рефералы не добавляються.

```
channel_ids = ['-1001630924118']
for channel_id in channel_ids:
    # Проверка подписки пользователя на канал
    result = bot.get_chat_member(channel_id, message.chat.id)
    if result.status in ['member', 'administrator', 'creator']:
        db[str(message.chat.id)] = {"balance": 0, "ref": 0, "earn": 0, "refp": "Користувач", "vs": 0,
                                    'user': message.from_user.id, 'userparrent': 'Nikto'}
        db[refcode]["ref"] = db[refcode]["ref"] + 1

        db[refcode]["earn"] = db[refcode]["earn"] + 1.00  # + 1 реферал
        db[refcode]["balance"] = db[refcode]["balance"] + 1.00
        save_db()
```